# How to impletement a multi-objective optimization in Optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner

I want to implement a multi-objective optimization with Optaplanner, and I have read the "Pareto Scoring" chapter in the document. I understood the principle of multi-objective planning in optaplanner, but don't actually know how to implement it, there are bellow queries:

1. How to design a custom score definition class, which class it should extend from, and what filed it should have basically?
2. As a multi-objective planning, I have to provide multiple solutions to the user. But the best solution is only one, how can I keep more than one solutions while planning? Does it mean, in the bestScoreChange event, I have to calculate the scores, find and keep the best solutions for each objective?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve? 

If you have two different goals can you simply run two different solvers at the same time with two different sets of rules?

Comment: I am developing a job shop project that a system makes a production planning every day. I got 2 goals for the production plan from the user - start the task as soon as possible and minimize the cost, these goals are different. after optaplanner solved, I want to provide the best solution for these each goal.
I don't think it's work to split the goals into a different set of rules and run them side by side, due to these goals have some dependencies to each other.

Answer (score 2):

If you really just have 2 goals, you can also fake it through running the Solver twice with different score levels in the @ConstraintWeights in the @ConstraintConfiguration class.

Real pareto solving is much more complex and requires adjustments to the BestScolutionRecaller, which is just the tip of the iceberg.